# How to call controller function from view in codeigniter?

Tags: php, view, controller

With codeigniter, I have a controller as in the following:

```
<?php if(!defined ('BASEPATH')) exit('not found basepath');

class **myController** extends CI_Controller{

    function __constructor(){
        parent::__constructor();
    }
    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('myview');
    }
    **public function myFn()**{
        echo "my controller is called"; 
    }
}

?>
```

and view is in the following:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>myController/myFn" method="post" name="myform">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

the problem is that when I run the view by going to localhost after clicking at the submit m intimating by the following error!

> The requested URL /CodeIgniter/myController/myFn was not found on this server.

but when I put `**http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/myController/myFn**` I got the correct output of the view

Comment: Hi @AliMohsin, if any of below answers has solved your question please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) the best answer or adding your own solution. So, that it indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller just delete ' ** '.

```
<?php if(!defined ('BASEPATH')) exit('not found basepath');

class myController extends CI_Controller{

    function __constructor(){
        parent::__constructor();
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('myview');
    }

    public function myFn(){
    echo "my controller is called"; 
    }
}
?>
```

And In your view try:

```
<?php echo form_open('myController/myFn'); ?>
<?php echo form_submit('submit','SUBMIT'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

when you run the view

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>myController/myFn" method="post" name="myform">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

use inspect element to see if the action in the form tag is same as

```
**http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/myController/myFn**
```

Comment: but u said it works on
http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/myController/myFn
and in form it is 
localhost/CodeIgniter/blog/myfn
see and tell me if both looks same to u

Comment: in case of putting index.php it shows the result but in case of link without index.php it doesn't show the out put.....

Comment: if you dont need to use index.php you will have to make changes in routes.php as well as htaccess and you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

if You Want to call controller function like this `/CodeIgniter/myController/myFn` then,
You have to remove index.php file using .htaccess file. First You change config.php file like this.

```
//  Remove index.php

$config['index_page'] = ""
```

then, create .htaccess file and copy this code to that file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Then, put this .htaccess file inside codeignator project folder.

To Reference see this link:- [enter link description here](https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-htaccess-remove-index-php/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to load URL helper

```
function test()
{

    $this->load->helper('url');
    $data['message']= $this->input->post('message');
    $this->load->view('backend/test',$data);

}
```

this might help you