# How to call function of controller in view using codeIgniter?

Tags: php, view, controller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to call controller function from view in codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682357/how-to-call-controller-function-from-view-in-codeigniter)

With codeigniter, I have a controller as in the following:

```
class myController extends CI_Controller{

    function __constructor(){
        parent::__constructor();
    }
    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('myview');
    }
    public function myFn(){
        echo "my controller is called"; 
    }
}
```

and in the view m using a HTML form in the form action m calling the myFn by using the following link localhost/Codeignator/myController/myFn
after doing so I got the following error!

> The requested URL /CodeIgniter/myController/myFn was not found on this server

but when I use the link localhost/Codeignator/index.php/myController/myFn

I got the correct output!

Comment: @AliMohsin, DON'T make "duplicate" or CLONE the questions. Don't waste your time.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the index.php file will be included in your URLs
see the  [user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html)  section Removing the index.php file about adding a .htacces

Create a .htaccess file with the following contents:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

and put it in the root folder of your site

Comment: hmm but if i don't include i got the error otherwise while including index.php i got the output as

Comment: the .htaccess will redirect to 'localhost/Codeignator/index.php/myController/myFn' if you go to 'localhost/Codeignator/myController/myFn'

Comment: how can i configure .htaccess file

Comment: the problem is solved by just changing the base url from http://localhost/ci to http://localhost/ci/index.php